When is explicitly knowledge of a kanji reading's category ('on', 'kun', etc) ever needed?
When is explicit knowledge of a kanji reading's category (on, kun, etc) ever needed? By this I mean knowledge of any of the following mappings:

(kanji, reading)-pair to category: eg being able to say explicitly whether かい is an on- or a kun- (or other) reading of 貝
(kanji, category)-pair to list of readings: eg being able to explicitly list all on- or kun-readings of 正 (perhaps restricted to the list of important ones)

special case: being able to list a kanji's most common on-reading



My understanding is that the main use of such explicit knowledge is to be able to pronounce previously unseen compound nouns in a way that is socially accepted and reasonably likely to be correct, and for this only the 'kanji's most common on-reading' special case is needed. But are there other uses? Note that for the purpose of this question, I consider things like "exams in Japanese language class in secondary school" or "level X of the Kanji Kentei (漢字検定)" to be valid use cases.
The following posts contain related content:

What's with this "On reading"/"Kun reading" thing? Is it important to learn both as a beginner?
Is the difference between On and Kun readings greater than just the pronunciation of the character?


You answered the question yourself, no?

Yes, it helps to know にく is actually an on-yomi to know にくじゅう is a more likely pronunciation than にくじる for 肉汁...

@Leebo (1) I'm absolutely a beginner; (2) my answers are educated guesses; (3) if my guesses are correct, it would be great if someone could supply additional information on the actual school subjects or Kanji Kentei levels.

Ever needed by who? A native Japanese speaker or a learner? I believe knowing about on/kun is clearly advantageous for leaners to efficiently remember words, bud don't you agree with that?

@naruto I more have in mind native speakers and the goal of achieving native-like proficiency (which doesn't encompass full knowledge of readings' categories). There are in fact people who argue that memorizing readings of kanji (and knowledge of the on vs kun label is part of that) is not that helpful, because readings are generally tied to vocabulary items (lexemes), and spoken language generally precedes written language (with occasional exceptions: sign languages produces by the fully deaf, some interactions with the writing system for East Asian languages).

My guess is also that it might be more useful to know about a character's most common reading (which may or may not be identical to one of the on readings) rather than about whether a reading is technically on (ie whether it is derived from a Chinese pronunciation).

It just seems like "ever needed" is a low bar that is easily cleared by the possibilities you suggested. The existence of Kanken and your awareness of it seems to fulfill it completely.

@Leebo My question isn't "whether ever"; it's intended to signify "where exactly (ever)". For example, does the Kanken require full knowledge of both mappings I described in my question? (It would surprise me if it did.)

There are levels of Kanken where you have to identify the reading category of an example. There are never times on Kanken where you are asked to just list things out, so I suppose that means the answer to your question is "no it's not required." I feel like details about the specific levels of Kanken aren't on-topic (since they are more about a specific test than the Japanese language itself), but you can always check out the official website for sample tests.

@Leebo Thanks. This means that the '(kanji, reading)-pair to category'-mapping is tested in the Kanji Kentei. However note that my original post was not a yes-no question. // Someone once told me that beyond level 2, the Kanji Kentei is basically a "kanbun (漢文) proficiency test". This implies that up to that level, it does have relevance for ordinary citizens.

If you were born in Japan and are learning Japanese as a native speaker, you don't need explicit knowledge of on/kun-readings at all to be able to speak or read Japanese fluently. Well, likewise, no explicit knowledge of grammar is required, either.
In the third grade of elementary school, every Japanese child learns about the existence of on/kun readings, so it can be assumed that most Japanese people have a basic understanding of what on/kun readings are, just as most English speakers know what nouns or adjectives are. However, such knowledge has little to do with the ability to speak Japanese fluently on a daily basis. Most Japanese people rely on intuition rather than explicit reasoning about on/kun readings when guessing the pronunciation of unfamiliar words, and I believe they can do this even if they hadn't learned about on/kun readings at all in elementary school. Of course, such knowledge is necessary for performing well on exams, especially entrance exams.
On the other hand, if you are over 13 and wish to master Japanese as a second language, it goes without saying that having explicit knowledge of the grammar and the rules of kanji readings is useful. (Of course, simply memorizing a list of kanji readings without understanding their meanings is clearly very inefficient, and I basically agree with the advice that you should learn kanji readings naturally as you learn new words.)

Is it normally the case that if a kanji has multiple meanings that aren't obviously related ("obvious": obvious to an ordinary person who hasn't given this much thought), these meanings often go with different sets of readings?

@LoverofStructure It depends, but we really don't consciously think about on, kun, ateji or jukujikun when we recognize words. Please read this. By the way, when it comes to spelling-pronunciation consistency, English is also one of the worst.

Yes. By the way I think Irish Gaelic is worse (and Scottish Gaelic supposedly even worse) – at least in the pronunciation-to-spelling direction (but probably in both directions, unlike what some people claim). Tibetan is similarly bad or even further on the difficulty scale. I also heard things about Thai in this regard, though it seems to me to be not that bad, based on superficial inspection.

As for the "rules of kanji readings", is my impression correct that there are many sub-rules, effectively amounting to kanji-specific patterns? (Example: "月 is がつ exactly when it designates a specific month of the year or combines with なん/何." – seemingly true as far as I as a beginner can tell, but do correct me if there are exceptions.) If so, can you recommend a good source which attempts to list them explicitly (for those kanji for which patterns are observable and easily describable)?

@LoverofStructure Are you saying you want more examples similar to 楽 or 悪 in this answer? Unfortunately, these are not rules but rather "useful patterns" at best. You'll intuitively notice such patterns as you memorize many words, but trying to learn patterns first is not very useful because there are so many exceptions.

Yes. I am wondering whether there are publications that attempt to systematically provide such rules, with lists of exceptions. (To be fair, stress and vowel length in English are also fairly random and sometimes different in AmE vs BrE, and no publication attempts to provide rules to be taught, afaik. Still, some books do something like this (for readings of so-called 多音字, ie characters with multiple pronunciations in Chinese) for Mandarin.)

@LoverofStructure This 漢和辞典 seems to include such information. See the example entry of 楽.

This is very valuable information; thanks a lot!
